# Django 2.0 - Trying to show detail record from a URL that has 2 pk segments

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble getting 2 pk segments in my URL to filter my view.  The first pk segment is the client's ID and the second pk segment is the server record id.  I have tried not using the default pk and instead using spk for the server id but I just keep getting errors no matter what I try. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Model**

```
class HardwareClientServers(models.Model):
    server_type = models.ForeignKey(HardwareServerTypes, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    os = models.ForeignKey(HardwareOperatingSystems, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    virtual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    memory = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    server_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
```

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.client_list, name='client_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ClientsDetailView.as_view(), name='client_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/serverlist/', views.ServerListView.as_view(), name='server_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/serverlist/<int:spk>/', views.ServerDetailView.as_view(), name='server_detail'),]
```

**View**

```
class ServerListView(ListView):
    model = models.HardwareClientServers
    context_object_name = 'client_servers'
    template_name = 'server_list.html'
    ordering = ['server_name']
    def get_queryset(self):
       return HardwareClientServers.objects.filter(client=self.kwargs['pk'])

class ServerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.HardwareClientServers
    context_object_name = 'client_server_details'
    template_name = 'server_details.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.spk = get_object_or_404(HardwareClientServers, id=self.kwargs['spk'])
    return HardwareClientServers.objects.filter(id=self.spk)
```

**The error I am getting**

```
TypeError at /clients/37563347/serverlist/1076/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'HardwareClientServers'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients/37563347/serverlist/1076/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'HardwareClientServers'
Exception Location: C:\Users\rbest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 947
Python Executable:  C:\Users\rbest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Client Support\\Django Projects\\TISRegister',
 'C:\\Users\\rbest\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\rbest\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\rbest\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\rbest\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\rbest\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have messed up the indentation in your example

```
class ServerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.HardwareClientServers
    context_object_name = 'client_server_details'
    template_name = 'server_details.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.spk = get_object_or_404(HardwareClientServers, id=self.kwargs['spk'])
        return HardwareClientServers.objects.filter(id=self.spk)
```

So the problem is `return HardwareClientServers.objects.filter(id=self.spk)` line.

Since self.spk is HardwareClientServers instance, you cannot use it for filter.
Instead, use

```
return HardwareClientServers.objects.filter(id=self.spk.id)
```

But better approach is to override `get_object`, not `get_queryset` method.
So the code becomes

```
class ServerDetailView(DetailView):
   model = models.HardwareClientServers
   context_object_name = 'client_server_details'
   template_name = 'server_details.html'

   def get_object(self):
       return get_object_or_404(HardwareClientServers, 
                                id=self.kwargs['spk'],
                                client=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In your detail view, your `get_queryset` method should return a queryset of the client’s objects, as it does in the list view.

```
class ServerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.HardwareClientServers
    context_object_name = 'client_server_details'
    template_name = 'server_details.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'spk'

    def get_queryset(self):
       return HardwareClientServers.objects.filter(client=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Setting `pk_url_kwarg = 'spk'` tells Django that `self.kwargs['spk']` should be used to fetch the object.

Alternatively, you can remove `get_queryset` and `pk_url_kwarg`, and override `get_object` instead, as shown in Александр Татаринов’s answer.